# Android change list view child text color based of what it says

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, textcolor

I am trying to change the color of a text view that is displayed in my list view. I'd like it to change based on what the text says. You'll see that I am attempting to do this in the onPostExecute method. The for loop does not iterate because the getChild call returns 0.

Here is my class:

```
    private class GetJSON extends
        AsyncTask<String, Integer, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> {

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> AmmoList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
        // Showing progress dialog before sending http request
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AmmoDisplay.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(AmmoDisplay.this, AmmoList,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_DESC, TAG_STOCK,
                        TAG_PRICE, TAG_RD, TAG_HREF }, new int[] {
                        R.id.desc, R.id.stock, R.id.price, R.id.rd,
                        R.id.href });
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        ListView lv = getListView();
        int childCount = lv.getCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
            View v = lv.getChildAt(i);
            TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.stock);
            String stockCol = tv.getText().toString();
            System.out.println(stockCol);
            if (stockCol == "in stock") {
                tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.in_stock));
            }
            if (stockCol == "out of stock") {
                tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.no_stock));
            }
        }

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                String href = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.href))
                        .getText().toString();
                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                        .parse(href));
                startActivity(browserIntent);
            }
        });
        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(
            String... params) {

        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(BASE_URL + AMMO);
        try {
            ammos = json.getJSONArray(TAG_AMMO);
            for (int i = 0; i < ammos.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = ammos.getJSONObject(i);

                String stock = c.getString(TAG_STOCK);
                String desc = c.getString(TAG_DESC);
                String price = c.getString(TAG_PRICE);
                String rd = c.getString(TAG_RD);
                String href = c.getString(TAG_HREF);

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                map.put(TAG_STOCK, stock);
                map.put(TAG_DESC, desc);
                map.put(TAG_PRICE, price);
                map.put(TAG_RD, rd);
                map.put(TAG_HREF, href);

                AmmoList.add(map);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return AmmoList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a `SimpleAdapter`.  Create a custom adapter that overrides `getView` and make whatever manipulations that you want to the text color based on the current item's text.

The logic will be simpler and clearer than trying to go through the list afterwards.

See `/samples/android-8/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List5.java` in your Android SDK folder (download appropriate samples as necessary) for a simple example:

```
private class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
...
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView tv;
        if (convertView == null) {
            tv = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(
                    android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, parent, false);
        } else {
            tv = (TextView) convertView;
        }
        tv.setText(mStrings[position]);
        return tv;
    }
...
}
```

Comment: I'm still having trouble with this, i'm not sure if it is because i'm using a hashmap?

Comment: @almyz125 You can use `getItem(position)` in an `ArrayAdapter` to retrieve your hashmap, and then retrieve whatever values you need from it.

Comment: I'm having trouble with a custom adapter I posted a new question here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19712734/custom-list-adapter-not-working-json-to-android-list