# Custom List adapter not working JSON to android list

Tags: java, android, json, listadapter

I am trying to make a custom list adapter by following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0TulTqQM0Cc#t=169). I'm having trouble when when my object gets items from my JSON data and adds it to the list. I've been able to use the simple list adapter and a hash map. I'd like to get away from the simple list adapter and hash maps. Here is my stack trace:

```
10-31 13:17:19.985: E/AndroidRuntime(15047): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-31 13:17:19.985: E/AndroidRuntime(15047): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-31 13:17:19.985: E/AndroidRuntime(15047):    at com.almyz125.ammobot.MainActivity$ViewHolder.<init>(MainActivity.java:62)
10-31 13:17:19.985: E/AndroidRuntime(15047):    at com.almyz125.ammobot.MainActivity$FancyAdapter.getView(MainActivity.java:44)
10-31 13:17:19.985: E/AndroidRuntime(15047):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java)
10-31 13:17:19.985: E/AndroidRuntime(15047):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java)
10-31 13:17:19.985: E/AndroidRuntime(15047):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java)
10-31 13:17:19.985: E/AndroidRuntime(15047):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java)
10-31 13:17:19.985: E/AndroidRuntime(15047):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java)
10-31 13:17:19.985: E/AndroidRuntime(15047):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java)
10-31 13:17:19.985: E/AndroidRuntime(15047):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java)
10-31 13:17:19.985: E/AndroidRuntime(15047):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java)
10-31 13:17:19.985: E/AndroidRuntime(15047):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java)
10-31 13:17:19.985: E/AndroidRuntime(15047):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java)
10-31 13:17:19.985: E/AndroidRuntime(15047):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java)
10-31 13:17:19.985: E/AndroidRuntime(15047):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java)
10-31 13:17:19.985: E/AndroidRuntime(15047):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java)
10-31 13:17:19.985: E/AndroidRuntime(15047):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java)
10-31 13:17:19.985: E/AndroidRuntime(15047):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java)
10-31 13:17:19.985: E/AndroidRuntime(15047):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java)
10-31 13:17:19.985: E/AndroidRuntime(15047):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java)
10-31 13:17:19.985: E/AndroidRuntime(15047):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java)
10-31 13:17:19.985: E/AndroidRuntime(15047):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java)
10-31 13:17:19.985: E/AndroidRuntime(15047):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java)
10-31 13:17:19.985: E/AndroidRuntime(15047):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java)
10-31 13:17:19.985: E/AndroidRuntime(15047):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java)
10-31 13:17:19.985: E/AndroidRuntime(15047):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java)
10-31 13:17:19.985: E/AndroidRuntime(15047):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java)
10-31 13:17:19.985: E/AndroidRuntime(15047):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java)
10-31 13:17:19.985: E/AndroidRuntime(15047):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java)
10-31 13:17:19.985: E/AndroidRuntime(15047):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java)
10-31 13:17:19.985: E/AndroidRuntime(15047):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
10-31 13:17:19.985: E/AndroidRuntime(15047):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
10-31 13:17:19.985: E/AndroidRuntime(15047):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
10-31 13:17:19.985: E/AndroidRuntime(15047):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-31 13:17:19.985: E/AndroidRuntime(15047):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
10-31 13:17:19.985: E/AndroidRuntime(15047):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
10-31 13:17:19.985: E/AndroidRuntime(15047):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
10-31 13:17:19.985: E/AndroidRuntime(15047):    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:115)
10-31 13:17:19.985: E/AndroidRuntime(15047):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my main_activity:

```
package com.almyz125.ammobot;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private String apiURLBase, ammoCat;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    ArrayList<Ammo> arrayJSONList = new ArrayList<Ammo>();
    private JSONArray ammos;
    private FancyAdapter fa = null;

    public class Ammo {
        public String href;
        public String desc;
        public String stock;
        public String price;
        public String rd;
    }

    public class FancyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Ammo> {
        FancyAdapter() {
            super(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    arrayJSONList);
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);

            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            holder.populateFrom(arrayJSONList.get(position));
            return (convertView);
        }
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        public TextView desc = null, href = null, round = null,
                stock = null, price = null;

        ViewHolder(View row) {
            desc = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.desc);
            href = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.href);
            round = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.rd);
            stock = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.stock);
            price = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.price);
        }

        void populateFrom(Ammo r) {
            desc.setText(r.desc);
            href.setText(r.href);
            round.setText(r.rd);
            stock.setText(r.stock);
            price.setText(r.price);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        apiURLBase = getString(R.string.api_base_url);
        ammoCat = "22lr";

        new GetJSONTask().execute();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private class GetJSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<Ammo>> {


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            if (pDialog != null) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Ammo> valid) {
            if (pDialog != null) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }

                            ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.mainList);
            fa = new FancyAdapter();
            lv.setAdapter(fa);

        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<Ammo> doInBackground(String... arg0) {

            try {
                JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
                JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(apiURLBase + ammoCat);
                ammos = json.getJSONArray(ammoCat);

                //System.out.println(ammos.toString());

                for (int i = 0; i < ammos.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject json_data = ammos.getJSONObject(i);

                    Ammo resultRow = new Ammo();
                    resultRow.desc = json_data.getString("desc");
                    resultRow.href = json_data.getString("href");
                    resultRow.price = json_data.getString("price");
                    resultRow.stock = json_data.getString("stock");
                    resultRow.rd = json_data.getString("rd");

                    arrayJSONList.add(resultRow);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(ammoCat, "Error:", e);
            }

            return arrayJSONList;
        }

    }

}
```

Here is my JSON parser class:

```
    package com.almyz125.ammobot;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

The error is coming from line 62 which is this class:

```
public class ViewHolder {
    public TextView desc = null, href = null, round = null,
            stock = null, price = null;

    ViewHolder(View row) {
        desc = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.desc);
        href = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.href);
        round = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.rd);
        stock = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.stock);
        price = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.price);
    }

    void populateFrom(Ammo r) {
        desc.setText(r.desc);
        href.setText(r.href);
        round.setText(r.rd);
        stock.setText(r.stock);
        price.setText(r.price);
    }

}
```

and this line:

```
desc = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.desc);
```

New adapter class:

```
public class FancyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Ammo> {
    FancyAdapter() {
        super(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                arrayJSONList);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.populateFrom(arrayJSONList.get(position));
        return (convertView);
    }
}
```

I'm now getting this stack:

```
    10-31 13:30:27.065: E/AndroidRuntime(16085): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-31 13:30:27.065: E/AndroidRuntime(16085): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-31 13:30:27.065: E/AndroidRuntime(16085):    at com.almyz125.ammobot.MainActivity$FancyAdapter.getView(MainActivity.java:53)
10-31 13:30:27.065: E/AndroidRuntime(16085):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java)
10-31 13:30:27.065: E/AndroidRuntime(16085):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java)
10-31 13:30:27.065: E/AndroidRuntime(16085):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java)
10-31 13:30:27.065: E/AndroidRuntime(16085):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java)
10-31 13:30:27.065: E/AndroidRuntime(16085):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java)
10-31 13:30:27.065: E/AndroidRuntime(16085):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java)
10-31 13:30:27.065: E/AndroidRuntime(16085):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java)
10-31 13:30:27.065: E/AndroidRuntime(16085):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java)
10-31 13:30:27.065: E/AndroidRuntime(16085):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java)
10-31 13:30:27.065: E/AndroidRuntime(16085):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java)
10-31 13:30:27.065: E/AndroidRuntime(16085):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java)
10-31 13:30:27.065: E/AndroidRuntime(16085):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java)
10-31 13:30:27.065: E/AndroidRuntime(16085):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java)
10-31 13:30:27.065: E/AndroidRuntime(16085):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java)
10-31 13:30:27.065: E/AndroidRuntime(16085):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java)
10-31 13:30:27.065: E/AndroidRuntime(16085):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java)
10-31 13:30:27.065: E/AndroidRuntime(16085):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java)
10-31 13:30:27.065: E/AndroidRuntime(16085):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java)
10-31 13:30:27.065: E/AndroidRuntime(16085):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java)
10-31 13:30:27.065: E/AndroidRuntime(16085):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java)
10-31 13:30:27.065: E/AndroidRuntime(16085):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java)
10-31 13:30:27.065: E/AndroidRuntime(16085):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java)
10-31 13:30:27.065: E/AndroidRuntime(16085):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java)
10-31 13:30:27.065: E/AndroidRuntime(16085):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java)
10-31 13:30:27.065: E/AndroidRuntime(16085):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java)
10-31 13:30:27.065: E/AndroidRuntime(16085):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java)
10-31 13:30:27.065: E/AndroidRuntime(16085):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java)
10-31 13:30:27.065: E/AndroidRuntime(16085):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
10-31 13:30:27.065: E/AndroidRuntime(16085):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
10-31 13:30:27.065: E/AndroidRuntime(16085):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
10-31 13:30:27.065: E/AndroidRuntime(16085):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-31 13:30:27.065: E/AndroidRuntime(16085):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
10-31 13:30:27.065: E/AndroidRuntime(16085):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
10-31 13:30:27.065: E/AndroidRuntime(16085):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
10-31 13:30:27.065: E/AndroidRuntime(16085):    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:115)
10-31 13:30:27.065: E/AndroidRuntime(16085):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The error seems to be here:

```
    holder.populateFrom(arrayJSONList.get(position));
```

Still getting an error at the above line.

here is my get view now:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.populateFrom(arrayJSONList.get(position));
        return (convertView);
    }
```

Comment: `MainActivity.java:62` what's there ?

Comment: desc = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.desc);

Answer (score 0):

Try setting Adapter in `onPostExecute` **because you can not update the UI from worker thread.**

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Ammo> valid) {
            if (pDialog != null) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }
           ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.mainList);
            fa = new FancyAdapter();
            lv.setAdapter(fa);
        }
```

Edit:-  Define `Ammo` class like below

```
public class Ammo {
    public String href;
    public String desc;
    public String stock;
    public String price;
    public String rd;

    public Ammo(String href, String desc, String stock, String price, String rd) {
        this.href = href;
        this.desc = desc;
        this.stock = stock;
        this.price = price;
        this.rd = rd;
    }

    public String getHref() {
        return href;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public String getStock() {
        return stock;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public String getRd() {
        return rd;
    }

}
```

Comment: I did that and now my stack trace is smaller. I'll post it above.

Comment: @almyz125 now what is the problem?

Comment: I edited the main post, the new stack trace is in the spot the old one is and i changed the main activity onPostExecute to show how i'm running it now.

Comment: still getting an error here:

holder.populateFrom(arrayJSONList.get(position));

Comment: quick question, though : what's the point of having public members in a class _and_ getter to access them, beside confusing the developer ?

Comment: @ I modified to understand  use of Get and set method not about modifiers. Better to use Model class out side the Activity. but if will do that developer will confuse to make all these changes.

Answer (score 0):

`ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);`

In this line, convertView may be null. You need to move this line inside the if block, after you have inflated `convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);`

Comment: I did that and i'm now getting an error on line 53, i edited the main post with the info.

Comment: see Jonathan's answer. You are not putting the holder in the tag of the view, therefore cannot get it back with getTag.

Answer (score 0):

as njzk2 said you must move `ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);` after the creation of the view.

And you must also set `convertView.setTag(holder);`, otherwise you will have a `NullPointerException` when getting to `holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();`

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

        holder.populateFrom(arrayJSONList.get(position));
        return (convertView);
    }
```

Comment: Just tried i'm still getting an error at line 54:  holder.populateFrom(arrayJSONList.get(position));

I edited the main post.

Comment: inverse your lines: convertView.setTag(holder) and holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);